# Is there anyway to error check my code for capitals other then the way that was hash tagged?

Tags: python-3.x

HELP? I need to calculate the amount of discount that is accumulated based on a previous set of code... but every time I include the hashtagged line of code under my "rewardsCard" variable, trying to make sure even if capitals are entered the code will still work, it runs the program but doesn't run any of the nested ifs.. it doesn't print anything after I say "yes".

When I run it without the hashtagged segment in produces all the code and works perfectly fine except i can not use capitals in my input (error check)

```
rewards = int(input('How many reward points do you have? (0 for none): '))

if rewards >= 15 and rewards <=24:
    print('you currently have', rewards, 'point(s).\n' 'You qualify for a 10% discount.')
elif (rewards >= 25 and rewards <= 49):
    print('you currently have', rewards, 'point(s).\n' 'You qualify for a 20% discount.')
elif (rewards >= 50 and rewards <= 74):
    print('you currently have', rewards, 'point(s).\n' 'You qualify for a 25% discount.')
if rewards == 0:
    rewardsCard = input('Would you like a rewards card? (Yes/No): ')
    #rewardsCard = rewardsCard.islower()
    if rewardsCard == 'yes':
        print('You currently have', rewards, 'point(s).\n' 'You qualify for a new member reward of 1 point and a 5% discount.')
    if rewardsCard == 'no':
        print ('You are not a rewards club member.\nSorry - no discount today!')
else:
    print('you currently have', rewards, 'point(s).\n' 'Sorry - no discount today!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just testing if are lower or capitals. You should change it to lower() instead of islower(), so you will convert your input to lower letters. islower onloy tests if all letters are lower and returns a boolean value:

```
rewards = int(input('How many reward points do you have? (0 for none): '))

if rewards >= 15 and rewards <=24:
    print('you currently have', rewards, 'point(s).\n' 'You qualify for a 10% discount.')
elif (rewards >= 25 and rewards <= 49):
    print('you currently have', rewards, 'point(s).\n' 'You qualify for a 20% discount.')
elif (rewards >= 50 and rewards <= 74):
    print('you currently have', rewards, 'point(s).\n' 'You qualify for a 25% discount.')
if rewards == 0:
    rewardsCard = input('Would you like a rewards card? (Yes/No): ')
    if rewardsCard.lower() == 'yes':
        print('You currently have', rewards, 'point(s).\n' 'You qualify for a new member reward of 1 point and a 5% discount.')
    if rewardsCard.lower() == 'no':
        print ('You are not a rewards club member.\nSorry - no discount today!')
else:
    print('you currently have', rewards, 'point(s).\n' 'Sorry - no discount today!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean to use `lower` instead of `is_lower`. The latter function returns a Boolean and breaks your code as it expects a string.

Comment: Thank you I wasn't really understanding why .islower() wouldn't work and its more clear now! So is the .islower function returns True or False instead of converting?

Comment: Exactly! And because Python is not strongly typed, your program will continue without a hitch. But if course when comparing the Boolean value to yes or no, it will never be equal.